# Send data in AJAX without concatenating a string

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have this AJAX call:

```
function editVehicule(test) {
  var entityId = $(test).attr('data-value');
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Controller/Method",
    data: "{'idtest':'" + entityId + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
  });
}
```

In this case, I'm using concatenation to pass the data. I'm looking for a proper way to achieve that. Is there one?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, use an object instead: `data: { idtest: entityId }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare your dataset as shown below:

```
function editVehicule(test) {
          var entityId = $(test).attr('data-value');

          var entity_data={idtest:entityId}; //this is how u can prepare ur dataset
          entity_data = JSON.stringify(entity_data);

          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Controller/Method",
            data: entity_data,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
          });
    }
```